# Compare list of strings and string to find number of consecutive character matches

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting

Im sure this has been done before, but what Im really trying to do is have a method that finds consecutive matches of characters for one string, within a set of multiple strings, with any matches less than 1 character match, not counting. (minimum of 2).

if the string to test with was "xx Audible 5", the following would be the result

1. Audible xxx-xxx-5051 NJ ----- Result:10 (matches 'Audible' and 'xx')
2. yy Audible ----- Result:8 (Audible)
3. Audible 5 xy  ----- Result:9 (spaces count, so match is Audible 5)
4. Audible.com 5  ----- Result:7

Comment: I don't see why it's 9 for the first case. In the string  "xx Audible 5" we have "xx" comes first " Audible". How do you define a match in your problem?

Comment: By your rules (spaces count), the result of the first example should be 10. That is, "Audible<space>xx". That's 10 characters. Also, if spaces count then the result for #2 should be 8. Either that or you need to refine your rules. For example, if the string was `"        Audible"` (that's 8 spaces and the word "Audible"), would the result be 15, or 7? What if it was "xx        Audible"?

Comment: @jim i have updated it. Thanks forpoiting out. So its always the amount of matches (of more than 1) added together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This is not optimized but it works pretty well

```
static int FindMatch(string text, string pattern)
    {
        var total = 0;           
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
        {
            var max = 0;               
            for (int j = 2; j <= pattern.Length - i; j++)
            {
                var temp = pattern.Substring(i, j);
                if (text.Contains(temp))                   
                    if (max < temp.Length)                        
                        max = temp.Length; 
            }
            total += max;
            if (max > 0)
                i += max-1;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

- `FindMatch("Audible xxx-xxx-5051 NJ", "xx Audible 5");`  returns 10
- `FindMatch("yy Audible", "xx Audible 5");`  returns 8
- `FindMatch("Audible 5 xy", "xx Audible 5");`  returns 9
- `FindMatch("Audible.com 5", "xx Audible 5");`  returns 9 too and not 7 because as I understood in this example would fail space 5 " 5"

Comment: If I could help you, please mark the answer as correct